# Cplex list all model variables (.NET)

Tags: cplex

Is there a way to list all cplex variables from a cplex model? I'm interested in the C# interface. Googling leads to [this solution](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21429472) IF your model is read in from a file. If your model has not been read in from a file, then no ILPMatrix is found in the model (unless you have specifically created LPMatrix's).

I guess I could write it out and read it back in:

```
Cplex m = new Cplex();
// add lots of variables with lots of different names and constraints
// perhaps even solve the model: m.Solve();

// now list out the variables:
m.ExportModel("myModel.lp");
m.ImportModel("myMOdel.lp");
m.Solve();

IEnumerator mEnum = m.GetLPMatrixEnumerator();
mEnum.MoveNext();
ILPMatrix lpmatrix = (ILPMatrix)mEnum.Current;
double[] x = m.GetValues(lpmatrix);
for (int j = 0; j < lpmatrix.NumVars.Length; ++j)
    System.Console.WriteLine("Variable Name:" + lpmatrix.GetNumVar(j).Name + "; Value = " + x[j]);
```

but it seems like there should be a better way. Am I missing something?

For comparison, here is the code to do the same for a Gurobi model:

```
foreach (GRBVar var in m.GetVars())
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", var.Get(GRB.StringAttr.VarName), var.Get(GRB.DoubleAttr.X));
```

Comment: From memory there are iterators over the various parts of an IloModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not. You can keep variable objects in a list or array though and access their value as follows:

```
...
Cplex     cplex = new Cplex();
INumVar[] varArray = new INumVar[nVariables];
...
foreach (var v in varArray)
   Console.WriteLine(cplex.GetValue(v).ToString());
```